# Replacing and adding text with REGEX

Tags: regex

Good day superusers. This is my first time posting here, I need some help with this.

**Note:
I am editing this question because it has been tagged as too broad.**

I would like to know how to repeat the last line of a text file using regular expressions.

For example, in the following text:

```
JASC-PAL
0100
4
90 57 33
107 140 66
123 198 123
255 255 181
```

I would like to repeat the last line of the file (**255 255 181**), until the line number reaches **259**.

Is this possible using regular expressions, or should I use another text manipulation tool?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should look at [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html), but there's a lot to learn. For myself I'd find it easier to knock up a quick C program to do it.

Comment: OK, I have been investigating, and have found the way to replacing the third line with "256" text:

Search:

0100\r\n.*\r\n

Replace with:

0100\r\n256\r\n

But still have not found the way to repeat the last lines.